# How to reverse the default color palette for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reverse the color map for a plot using `scale_color_brewer(direction = -1)`. However, doing so also changes the palette.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()

# reverse colors
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()+
  scale_color_brewer(direction = -1)
```

Potential solution

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()+
scale_color_brewer(direction = -1, palette = ?)
```

Comment: Updated the title

Comment: Don't have an answer, but the default scale is `scale_color_discrete`, not a color brewer scale. It calls `discrete_scale` specifying the palette as `scales::hue_pal`, and *does* take a `direction` argument, but adding `scale_color_discrete(direction = -1)` changes the palette more than just reversing. Don't have time to dig more in right now...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default color palette ggplot uses is `scale_color_hue`.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()
```

is equivalent to

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) +
  geom_point() + scale_color_hue(direction = 1)
```

`direction = -1` does reverse the colors. But then you need to adjust the starting point in the hue wheel, in order to get the same three colors in reversed order.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()+
  scale_color_hue(direction = -1, h.start=90)
```

Each color moves the hue pointer 30 degrees. So we set the starting point at 90.

[image: hue wheel]

BTW, in order to let `scale_colour_brewer` work for categorical variables, you need to set `type = 'qual'`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()+
  scale_color_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 'Dark2')
```

Comment: And to reverse the default continuous color scale, you can use `scale_color_continuous(trans = 'reverse')` similar to how you would reverse a continuous axis scale.

Comment: I use the 'paired' palette and would want to move one discrete jump up, how would I do that? I wanna start with the dark blue not the light blue!

Comment: It doesn't work with `geom_hex`

Answer (score 8):

We can use the `hue_pal` function from the `scales` package to get the name of the colors. After that, use `scale_color_manual` to specify the color with `rev` to reverse the order of the colors from `hue_pal`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Get the colors with 3 classes
cols <- hue_pal()(3)

# Plot the data and reverse the color
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = rev(cols))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `scale_color_manual()` for more control. Here are two versions with reversed color maps.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()+
+     scale_color_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'Blues'))

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+geom_point()+
+     scale_color_manual(values = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'Blues')))
```