# How to change the order of aesthetic layers in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

How can I change the order of aestetics layers?
Here's and example

```
dat <- tibble (acc = rep(c(0,1), 200),
               rt = rnorm(400, 0.5, 0.1))

dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

This code plots this image. Here, the green (1) layer is above the red (0) layer. How can I place the red (0) layer on top of the green (1)?

I have tried

```
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc, levels = c(1,0)))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)
```

but this results in switching colors **and** positions!

[image]

Comment: have you tried changing the level order? e.g. `factor(acc, levels = c(1,0))`?

Comment: Yes, but this switches the colors, and positions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could re-order the levels of your `factor` and add the color adjustment:

```r
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, 
                   fill = factor(acc, levels = c(1,0)))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("1" = "#00BFC4", "0" = "#F8766D"))
```

Comment: Can you please be more precise with the code for color adjustment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Usually it's very simple, just adding `direction= -1` to your `scale_fill` function. But this does not currently work.

If you want to keep the ggplot2 default palette (which I think may not be the best idea), then the following approach works ([inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45869216/7941188))

With the latest `scale` package v.1.1.0 , the `direction = -1` argument seems to break the `scale::hue_pal()` function ([see this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062827/change-direction-of-fill-color-aesthetic-of-default-palette) or [this github bug report](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/252)), so here would be a workaround with explicitely calling `scales::hue_pal` in order to create your palette.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  acc = rep(c(0, 1), 200),
  rt = rnorm(400, 0.5, 0.1)
)

dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc))) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count.. * 0.03), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(dat$acc)))))
```

[image]

I generally recommend rather to use other colors than the default palette. A good choice is colorbrewer - very good is [colorbrewer2.org](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=BuGn&n=3) which helps you finding good palettes.

An example using "Dark2":

```r
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc))) +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count.. * 0.03), alpha = 0.6) +
scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 'Dark2')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just wanted to add an answer concerning the brewer palettes, which is more straightforward.

So, original data:

```
dat <- tibble (acc = rep(c(0,1), 200),
               rt = rnorm(400, 0.5, 0.1))

dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Switch colors

```
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = -1)
```

[image]

Switch position

```
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc, levels = c(1,0)))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", direction = -1)
```

[image]

Switch position and color

```
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x = rt, fill = factor(acc, levels = c(1,0)))) + 
  geom_density(aes(y= ..count..*0.03), alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]