# ggplot - line ordering, one line on top of the other

Tags: ggplot2, colors, line

Here is my example:

```
library(ggplot2)

forecast <- c(2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3)
actual <- c(2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,1)

my_df <- data.frame(forecast = forecast, actual = actual)
my_df$seq_order <- as.factor(1:NROW(my_df))
my_df <-gather(my_df, "line_type", "value", -seq_order)


ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=seq_order, y = value,
  colour = line_type, group=line_type))+geom_line()+theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Here is how it looks:
[image: plot]

I would like to have red line to be on top of blue line everywhere where they coincide. I tried `scale_color_manual(values = c("forecast" = "red" ,"actual" = "blue"))`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the factor level order. Don't forget to change the group too.

[See this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60063053/7941188), why I used `scales::hue()` etc

```r
library(tidyverse)

forecast <- c(2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,3,3)
actual <- c(2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,1)

my_df <- data.frame(forecast = forecast, actual = actual, seq_order = 1:11) 
my_df <-gather(my_df, line_type, value, -seq_order) %>% mutate(type = factor(line_type, levels = c('forecast','actual')))


ggplot(data=my_df, aes(x=seq_order, y = value, 
                       colour = type, group = type)) +
  geom_line()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_color_manual(values = rev(scales::hue_pal()(2)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You  changed color, but I need actual to be on top of forecast. So in your plot, I would like to have up to 8 blue line.

Comment: Awesome it worked! Could you help me to decipher what it all means `values = rev(scales::hue_pal()(2))`

Comment: please have a look at the answer which I linked to ! I explain a bit there . Hope this helps