# change direction of fill/ color aesthetic of default palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

On pondering on [this very recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062311/how-to-change-the-order-of-aestetic-layers-in-ggplot) I noticed that reversing the factor levels does naturally not change the order of colors. I tried to add `direction = -1` in `scale_fill`/`scale_color` ("`_discrete`" and "`_hue`"), and was stunned by the weird result. I am not sure if there are more recent questions [than this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868625/how-to-reverse-the-default-color-palette-for-ggplot2), but the given code does produce the following weird result (regardless of the `h.start` argument). The same happens with `fill`

Bug? Or am I overlooking something?

(P.s. I don't really like the default colors and am never really using them. This is more of an academic question)

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_discrete(direction = -1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#>  version  R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.2.1   2019-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with R3.6.1, same ggplot2 version: I get three colours. Might be in one of the ggplot2 dependencies though?

Comment: @Tjebo: `scales` v.1.0.0 used `grDevices::hcl` in the `hue_pal` function (which works as expected), while v.1.1.0 uses `farver::encode_colour`, which does not. That might explain the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in the `scales::hue_pal` function. In that help page, one example is `show_col(hue_pal(direction = -1)(9))`, which (on my machine) gives the same color as in your example in all 9 tiles - and that is certainly not the intended outcome.
It seems like farver:::encode_c does not work as intended in that context.

Intuitively, I would just reverse the palette you get with `direction=1`, but the `scales::hue_pal` function generates negative hues that `farver::encode_colour` cannot deal with.
I am not sure this is the intended outcome (just reversing the order of the palette colors), but I would adjust the `scales::hue_pal` function like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

hue_pal <- function (h = c(0, 360) + 15, c = 100, l = 65, h.start = 0, direction = -1) 
{
    stopifnot(length(h) == 2)
    stopifnot(length(c) == 1)
    stopifnot(length(l) == 1)
    scales:::force_all(h, c, l, h.start, direction)
    function(n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            stop("Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.", 
                call. = FALSE)
        }
        if ((diff(h)%%360) < 1) {
            h[2] <- h[2] - 360/n
        }
        rotate <- function(x) (x + h.start)%%360 * direction
        hues <- rotate(seq(h[1], h[2], length.out = n))
        if(direction == -1) hues <- abs(rev(hues)) # my edit
        hcl <- cbind(hues, c, l)
        farver::encode_colour(hcl, from = "hcl")
    }
}

scale_color_discrete <- function (..., h = c(0, 360) + 15, c = 100, l = 65, h.start = 0, 
    direction = 1, na.value = "grey50", aesthetics = "colour") 
{
    discrete_scale(aesthetics, "hue", hue_pal(h, c, l, h.start, 
        direction), na.value = na.value, ...)
}


# reversed color palette
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_color_discrete(direction = -1)
```

[image]

```r
# standard palette
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_color_discrete(direction = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks I am glad I am not the only one who found this. I think I'll file a bug report.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3797... And a couple minutes later I found the more appropriate issue for scales: https://github.com/r-lib/scales/issues/252